# Custom JSON in Bootstrap.groovy Returns No Such Property Error for Domain

Tags: grails

I'm following the instructions on this [link](http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/02/15/rendering-json-in-grails-part-3-customise-your-json-with-object-marshallers/) which recommend I update my bootstrap groovy class.

```
// Bootstrap.groovy
import grails.converters.JSON

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(UserMapping) {
            def rA = [:]
            ra['userId'] = it.id
        }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

But it returns the error:

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: No such property: UserMapping for class: BootStrap
Message: No such property: UserMapping for class: BootStrap
```

My domain class looks like:

```
# UserMapping.groovy
package engagementlevels

class UserMapping {

    String username
    String email
    Date insertTime
    String type
    String flags

    static belongsTo = [groupMapping: GroupMapping]

    static mapping = {
        // Custom Mappings here
    }

    static hibernateFilters = {
        // Filters here
    }

    transient beforeInsert = {
        throw new RuntimeException('create not allowed')
    }
    transient beforeUpdate = {
        throw new RuntimeException('update not allowed')
    }
    transient beforeDelete = {
        throw new RuntimeException('delete not allowed')
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the "engagementlevels" package but BootStrap.groovy is in the default package. Add an import for the class:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import engagementlevels.UserMapping

class BootStrap {

   def init = { servletContext ->
       JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(UserMapping) {
          def rA = [userId: it.id]
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. I'll mark your answer as soon as it lets me.